# Java - Unit Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Given this method in a Java class:

```
public void execute(String command) {

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Process process = processBuilder.start();

    int exitValue = process.waitFor();
    if (exitValue != 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("a message here...");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to come up with a proper **cross platform** unit test for this method.

I'm looking for a common command across all operating systems (Win, Linux, Mac and ...) or a fake command that I can pass to this method in my unit tests.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: I think if you can run junit on all platform, then you can run a command of java with simple main class

Comment: Your method has return type `void`; it might help if it returned the `exitValue`.

Comment: @S.L.Barth The method throws an exception if a non-success exit-value is returned by the process, so returning the exitValue would be pointless, as 0 would be returned always.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This method can't be tested via a unit test but only via an integration test. To make a unit test you could do a small refactor. Introduce a new interface `ProcessBuilderFactory` (and a default implementation) and inject it on your class.

```
public interface ProcessBuilderFactory {
    ProcessBuilder createProcessBuilder(String command);
}

public class DefaultProcessBuilderFactory implements ProcessBuilderFactory {
    public ProcessBuilder createProcessBuilder(String command) {
        return new ProcessBuilder(command);
    }
}

public class ProcessExecutor {
    private ProcessBuilderFactory processBuilderFactory;
    private ProcessExecutor(ProcessBuilderFactory processBuilderFactory) {
        this.processBuilderFactory = processBuilderFactory;
    }

    public void execute(String command) {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = processBuilderFactory.createProcessBuilder(command);
        Process process = processBuilder.start();

        int exitValue = process.waitFor();
        if (exitValue != 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("a message here...");
        }
    }
}
```

and then you could make a **unit** test by injecting a mock `ProcessBuilderFactory`.
You start writing the test, you create a mock `ProcessBuilderFactory`, returning a mock `ProcessBuilder`... damned, `ProcessBuilder` is `final` too :(

**A strong reminder :  write the test first !**

So we have two options :

1. introduce a new interface for wrapping the `ProcessBuilder` with a default implementation... in the same way we create the `ProcessBuilderFactory`
2. undo the refactoring and look at [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/), for  final class mocking

Comment: Indeed, the test would simple test whether de proces is invoked  and handled properly. A different unittest should then test the correctness of the created processes by processBuilder.

Comment: I believe you won't be able to unit test the ProcessBuilderFactory, for the same reason that you cannot unit test the original method.

Comment: btw, ProcessBuilder itself is a FINAL class and I can't extend it. so I need to introduce another interface like MyProcessBuilder with a default implementation which is a wrapper around java ProcessBuilder. Sounds too much work for a unit test :)

Answer (score 2):

Since this is java unit test you could use java.exe as standard exe.  Say `java.exe -version`.  It will  always be there :).  Use current jdk from java.home and then use that to refer java.exe

Looking at specific requirement could you use any mocking framework? ([jmockit](http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/) for example)

Comment: Well, with the `.exe` there, it's not really cross-platform, is it :)? Also, this assumes that Java is on the path, which isn't always the case.

Comment: from your question, I thought, you need a command that gives some output in all test environment.  I thought you have java on all test environment. You can always find java.exe  and use absolute path.

Comment: What I mean is, on Linux and OS X, the file won't be called `java.exe`; that's only true on Windows. The OP explicitly asked for something that's cross-platform.